# How can I cache specific web pages for offline viewing?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, browser, offline

I occassionally need to work offline by accident or design. I'd like to maintain a flexible list of web pages that I can cache for easy offline access.

Notes:

- I'd like to simulate online browsing as closely as possible. So instructions on using "Offline mode" for Chrome/ium (preferable) or Firefox would be best. Or an extension for one of those browsers.
- But, any application will do. For example, I don't use Epiphany but if it's easiest to set up this cache in Epiphany, then Epiphany will become my offline browser :)
- Ideally I want to maintain a short list of URLs, and cache them *plus* every link on them (just 1 link deep will do). I would then maintain the web pages at the root URLs via various web applications. Some of these apps require authentication, so being able to store cookies is also important.
- But, I don't mind having to manually open application X every day to get enter these passwords and store the cache.

Comment: I don't need to do this anymore but another approach would be `httrack` / `webhttrack`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this I think you should give the Scrapbook extension for Firefox a try.

http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/

Comment: I ended up using Scrapbook Plus (it has few handy extra features I like) - thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is there anything similar for other web browsers (such as Google Chrome?)

Comment: There is Chromium scrapbook, but nothing as good as Scrapbook for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a "File > Work Offline" mode that will fetch everything from cache rather than fetching. Anything in cache will be displayed. (ie. No need to turn on "Work Offline" to get the pages to store.)

I haven't tried it between system sessions, but presumably it works. :)