# How to open web pages offline

Tags: firefox, wget

I want to completely save a webpage, so that when I open Firefox offline, I can navigate to this webpage and look into its contents.
I used wget for this.

> wget -m website.com
>
> wget -r website.com

But when I open Firefox offline and type this website, I get server not found.
How can I fix this, or find another way so that it works?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use File -> OpenFile (ctrl-o) to navigate to saved content. Alternatively, use [offline mode](http://www.wikihow.com/Work-Offline-in-Mozilla-Firefox). I don't think typing URLs will do much when offline.

Comment: Did you check this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/96516/how-can-i-cache-specific-web-pages-for-offline-viewing?rq=1

Comment: Is saving the page as `html`, with images and style included, good enough for you?

Comment: Read `man wget`. I use the `--no-parent --relative --page-requisites --convert-links -nv -t 3 --waitretry=6 --random-wait` options, myself. YMMV. Read `man wget`.

Comment: @M.Becerra I cannot archive my website in Scrapbook, because Scrapbook is not showing anywhere in Moxilla after I installed it. May you show how can I use it?

Comment: @M.Becerra I managed to capture the page, but it still doesn't work offline

Answer (score 0):

### Use WebHTTrack Website Copier

**Description**: Copy websites to your computer, httrack with a Web interface
 WebHTTrack is an offline browser utility, allowing you to download a World
 Wide website from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively
 all directories, getting html, images, and other files from the server to
 your computer, using a step-by-step web interface.

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install webhttrack
```

A good description of the functionality can be found on this [link](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/WebHTTrack-Website-Copier).